# Do people with brighter smiles feel brighter?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, emotion, empathy

People's facial shape when smiling are different. Some are bright, some looks like there's a bit embarrassment, others may be with a twist, even if they are all smiling from true happiness. 

These facial looks may give the observer different feelings, that is, seeing brighter smiles makes you feel happier too, or that you feel the smiler must be happier if she has a brighter smile on her face. ***Is this true?***

A step further. If you force a smile in your face, do brighter smiles induce brighter feelings?

Comment: Your last sentence is a separate question. So I would recommend removing it from this question and asking about the effects of forced smiling in a new question.